# Regex remove match prefix php

Tags: php, regex

I need a system where it will search for a string in a particular pattern, then add a particular HTML tag to it but remove the search string.

For example if the match string was `%%` and someone typed this `%%MyString` it should convert it to this `<p class="myClass">MyString </p>` without the `%%` in front of it.

Here's my code I tried. I think it has to do something with the `${99}`. I tried `$0` but that still gives me the match string.

```
function convertLabels($str){
    $regex = "/<(.*?)>[%]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)<(.*?)>/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="listhash.php?tag=$1" class="label label-default">${99}</a>', $str);
    $regex = "/<(.*?)>[%%]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)<(.*?)>/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="listhash.php?tag=$1" class="label label-primary">${99}</a>', $str);
    $regex = "/<(.*?)>[%!]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)<(.*?)>/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="listhash.php?tag=$1" class="label label-info">${99}</a>', $str);
    $regex = "/<(.*?)>[%%!]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)<(.*?)>/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="listhash.php?tag=$1" class="label label-warning">${99}</a>', $str);
    $regex = "/<(.*?)>[%!!]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)<(.*?)>/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="listhash.php?tag=$1" class="label label-danger">${99}</a>', $str);
    return($str);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example input string and an expected output string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
function convertLabels($str){
  $regex = "/%%([^\s]+)/";
  $str = preg_replace($regex, '<p class="myClass">${1}</p>', $str);

  return $str;
}


echo convertLabels("wrap the %%text with a p tag");
```

Output:

```
wrap the <p class="myClass">text</p> with a p tag
```

Explanation:

`[^\s]+` ... one or more arbitrary characters (excluding space characters)

`${1}` is a backreference to the first parenthesized expression in the pattern, which is `([^\s]+)`, and that means all text between `%%` and the next occuring space character.

Comment: Yes that is what I want... I see